# Why do parentheses make my regex not match?

Tags: c#, regex

This matches:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("15, 17-19", @"^\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*(?:-\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*)?(?:,\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*(?:-\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*)?)*$"));
```

But when I add parentheses after the ^ and before the $ it doesn't

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("15, 17-19", @"^(\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*(?:-\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*)?(?:,\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*(?:-\s*\d\d|\d\d\d\d\s*)?)*)$"));
```

Can anyone tell me why?

**Update:**

I see now that my original expression was wrong. I should have had my `\d\d|\d\d\d\d` portions enclosed in a non-capturing group like this:

```
^\s*(?:\d\d|\d\d\d\d)\s*(?:-\s*(?:\d\d|\d\d\d\d)\s*)?(?:,\s*(?:\d\d|\d\d\d\d)\s*(?:-\s*(?:\d\d|\d\d\d\d)\s*)?)*$
```

Which could also be written as

```
^\s*(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s*(?:-\s*(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s*)?(?:,\s*(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s*(?:-\s*(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s*)?)*$
```

This would allow me to add additional parentheses as needed without changing the behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I'd definitely consider simplifying it - replace `\d\d\d\d` with `\d{4}` for readability, and to make it shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second pattern with the parentheses makes the `^` and `$` metacharacters apply to the entire pattern, which means the entire string must match the pattern. In other words:

- Match beginning of string (`^`)
- Your pattern
- Match end of string (`$`)

Your first pattern was passing because it is actually being interpreted as `^pattern1` or `pattern2$`, thus it was partially matching the input rather than doing so entirely. The breakdown for this pattern is:

- Match beginning of string and first alternate (from `^` upto the pipe symbol)
- **Or** match the second alternate and the end of the string (after the pipe symbol till `$`)

Answer (score 2):

You have the pipe in the expression - it changes how the expression works when you add the parentheses.

Comment: In what way does it change it?

Comment: Ahmad Mageed posted a better answer that explains the change.